# Vuex float based store value stored as string

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I've created Vuejs frontend project on my desktop. I am using Vuex for the centralized state management. I've TotalAmount and Profit values on my states and I am trying to do addition and subtract operations for both of those states. Sure, decrease working well but increase function concatenate those to states.
Let's suppose:

```
TotalProfit:1.05465
Profit:0.0012
```

increase function returns on `1.054650.0012`.

**Store.js File:**

```
const state = {
    TotalBalance: 0,
    Profit:0.00000000
};
const actions = {
    setTotalBalance(context, data) {
        context.commit('setTotalBalance', parseFloat(data).toFixed(8))
    },
    increaseTotalBalance(context, data) {
        context.commit('increaseTotalBalance', parseInt(data).toFixed(8))
    },
    decreaseTotalBalance(context, data) {
        context.commit('decreaseTotalBalance', parseFloat(data).toFixed(8))
    },
    setProfit(context, data) {
        context.commit('setProfit', data)
    },
}
const mutations = {
    setTotalBalance(state,TotalBalance){
        state.TotalBalance = Number(parseFloat(TotalBalance).toFixed(8));
    },
    increaseTotalBalance(state,Balance){
        state.TotalBalance = Number(parseFloat(state.TotalBalance ).toFixed(8))+Number(parseFloat(Balance).toFixed(8))
    },
    decreaseTotalBalance(state,Balance){
        state.TotalBalance = parseFloat(state.TotalBalance ).toFixed(8)-parseFloat(Balance).toFixed(8)
    },
    setProfit(state,Profit){
        state.Profit = Number(parseFloat(Profit).toFixed(8))
    }
}
const getters = {
    getTotalBalance: state=>{
        return state.TotalBalance
    },
    getProfit: state => {
        return state.Profit
    }
}
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state,
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions
})
```

As you can see from the file above, I tried many different ways however not found any solution myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) returns a **string**, so you get concatenated strings. Instead you can just do `+string` to convert a string into number, and cut 8 digits in a getter when you need to display it:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    TotalBalance: 1.05465,
    Profit: 0.0012
  },
  mutations: {
    increaseTotalBalance(state,Balance){
      state.TotalBalance = +state.TotalBalance + +Balance;
    },
    decreaseTotalBalance(state,Balance){
      state.TotalBalance = +state.TotalBalance - +Balance;
    },
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  computed: {
    total: function() {
      return Number(this.$store.state.TotalBalance).toFixed(8);
    },
    profit: function() {
      return Number(this.$store.state.Profit).toFixed(8);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    inc: function() {
      this.$store.commit('increaseTotalBalance', this.profit)
    },
    dec: function() {
      this.$store.commit('decreaseTotalBalance', this.profit)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.0/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@2.3.1"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ total }}, {{ profit }}</p>
  <button @click="inc">Inc</button>
  <button @click="dec">Dec</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I really understand the issue on my implementation now. However, I am setting Total Amount field from `HTTP.get` response. When I am checking it on Vue debugger on Chrome, It's coming as same as a string with quotes. So what I am supposed to do to convert float?

Comment: Ahhhh. That's ok. I changed `response.body.TotalAmount` to `Number(response.body.TotalAmount)` and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @bl4cksta I'm glad it helped.